# phantomjs : Calling page.evaluate from some other function or module

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs to test many pages and trying to make my code cleaner. Is it possible to do page.open and call page.evaluate from some other function or module. 
Now :

```
page.open(ADDRESS, function(status) {
           if (status == 'success') {
              page.evaluate(function() {
                return document.querySelector('.error');
                ...... do some more checks
              }):
              .....Run some other code
           }
```

What I would like to do :

```
file check.js : exports.check = function() {
                 page.evaluate(function() {
                return document.querySelector('.error');
                ...... do some more checks
              }):
```

And in the main.js or other files I just call this function of check.js to do the checks. 
This probably needs to call this function by reference but am not sure how to do this. If this can be done, all my files size will decrease and the code will be more readable.

Comment: And you tried it, and what happened was...??

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.check = function(page){ page.evaluate(function() {
                return document.querySelector('.error');
                ...... do some more checks
              });
```

That's how I encapsulate my phantomJs into scripts

More Samples @ https://github.com/ImaginaryDevelopment/javascript/tree/master/phantom